# Classifying numerical data in column into range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of numbers which I would like to classify into the following ranges:
0-2%, 2%-3%, 3%-4, so on and so forth. It seems like a nested conditional would be too large, but I'm not sure how else to specify that the data will be classified into each range provided the condition that it is between the two numbers be met.

Comment: You need to provide some examples and the expected result for these explained, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula should return what you are after

```
=LET(
    lower,SEQUENCE(50,1,0,2) / 100,
    upper,lower + 2/100,
    INDEX(TEXT(lower,"0%")&"-"&TEXT(upper,"0%"),MATCH(1,(B2>=lower)*(B2<upper),0))
)
```

which looks as shown in this screenshot

[image: screenshot_1]

Note: the sequence covers [0%,100%) in steps of 2%.

---

Another formula to achieve the same result is

```
=TEXT(ROUNDDOWN(B2/2,2)*2,"0%")&"-"&TEXT(ROUNDUP(B2/2,2)*2,"0%")
```

This one is not limited to a range, however, for a percentage value that is exactly x.0%, it will return the range x.0%-x.0%. For example, if the percentage is exactly 6%, the range it returns will be 6%-6%.

So it should be adjusted to

```
=TEXT(ROUNDDOWN(B2/2,2)*2,"0%")&"-"&TEXT(1/IFERROR(1/(ROUNDUP(B2/2,2)*2-B2),50)+B2,"0%")
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what's required, but nice solution.